# CCSequence with two CCAction

Tags: cocos2d-x

I have two CCActions : 
CCAction *a;
CCAction *b;

so how to use CCSequence with two CCActions
Thanks

Answer (score 1):

```
CCFiniteTimeAction *example = CCSequence::create(a, b);
```

[CCSequence](http://www.cocos2d-x.org/embedded/cocos2d-x/dc/d7d/classcocos2d_1_1_c_c_sequence.html)

Alternatively you can just run the action on a sprite directly.

Comment: No, i'm coding cocos2d-x, not cocos2d, sorry, cocos2dx have less sample

Comment: @user919496 sorry wasn't paying attention to the tag I'll update my answer.

Comment: @user919496 I guess it should be something like `[CCsequence actions:a b null]` or equivalent Obj-C code!

Comment: now i find one solution :
i create one CCArray * arrayAction, then add all action into arrayAction
m_sprite-> runAction(CCSequence ::create(arrayAction));

Comment: You can do that also. It's in the documentation I linked. You can also do CCSequence::createWithTwoActions(a,b). That doesn't mean my original answer is wrong. Alternatively you can do it the way I said at the end. etc.etc.etc. You should really just go through the documentation.